# Amazon EC2 spot instances keep launching after termination

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am learning how to use `Amazon Web Services`.  I have successfully used a free tier `Amazon Web Service` instance to run `R` programs via `PuTTY` and `FileZilla`.  I am now trying to use a `Spot Instance` to do the same with a more powerful instance.

I have terminated an existing `Spot Instance`, but a second `Spot Instance` was generated spontaneously to take its place.  So, I terminated the second `Spot Instance` and a third was generated spontaneously.

I have not seen this behavior before when terminating free tier instances.  How do I terminate a `Spot instance` so it is not spontaneously replaced by another one?  My understanding is that I am being billed hourly from the time a `Spot Instance` is launched until it is terminated.

I am terminating instances by right-clicking on the `Instance ID`, then going to `Instance State > Terminate` on the pop-up menu.

Here are the details of the original `Spot Instance` if this information might be helpful. I am hiding portions of the `Instance ID`, the `IP`, the `Owner ID` and the `Reservation` and have provided a fake `key pair` name.

```
Instance ID: i-XXXXXa30498b1b9ca
Public DNS (IPv4): ec2-XX-XXX-XXX-XXX.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
Instance state: running
IPv4 Public IP: XX.XXX.XXX.XXX
Instance type: r4.xlarge
IPv6 IPs: -
Elastic IPs:
Private DNS: ip-XXX-XX-XX-XX.us-east-2.compute.internal
Availability zone: us-east-2b
Private IPs: XXX.XX.XX.XX
Security groups: default. view inbound rules. view outbound rules
Secondary private IPs
Scheduled events: No scheduled events
VPC ID: vpc-ce0c17a6
AMI ID: ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-bionic-18.04-amd64-server-20191002 (ami-0d5d9d301c853a04a)
Subnet ID: subnet-b3f881c9
Platform: -
Network interfaces: eth0
IAM role: -
Source/dest. Check: True
Key pair name: mykeyb
T2/T3 Unlimited: -
Owner: XXXXXXXXXXXX
EBS-optimized: False
Launch time: November 26, 2019 at 5:43:37 PM UTC-5 (1 hour)
Root device type: ebs
Termination protection: False
Root device: /dev/sda1
Lifecycle: spot
Block devices: /dev/sda1
Monitoring: basic
Elastic Graphics ID: -
Alarm status: None
Elastic Inference accelerator ID: -
Kernel ID: -
Capacity Reservation: -
RAM disk ID: -
Capacity Reservation Settings: Open
Placement group: -
Partition number: -
Virtualization: hvm
Reservation: r-XaecaXXbfXacXXXXX
AMI launch index: 0
Tenancy: default
Host ID: -
Affinity: -
State transition reason: -
State transition reason message: -
Stop - Hibernation behavior: Disabled
Number of vCPUs: 4
```

Here are additional details I have located.  Apparently the problem is that the `Persistence` option is set to `maintain`.  First I provide the definition of `Persistence`:

```
Persistent Spot fleet maintains the target capacity of the fleet over time by launching replacement instances after Spot instances in the fleet are terminated.
```

Here are the additional details with the `Request ID` changed:

```
Request Id: sfr-daeXXXeX-XXXX-XeXc-bXeX-XdXXXccXbXXf
Request type: fleet 
Created: 11/26/2019, 5:43:25 PM
State: active
Status: fulfilled 
Total target capacity: 4 (4 fulfilled) 
On-Demand capacity: 0 (0 fulfilled) 
Allocation strategy: capacityOptimized 
Instance type(s): c5.xlarge weight=4 $0.0425, r3.xlarge weight=4 $0.083, 
                  c5d.xlarge weight=4 $0.048, r4.xlarge weight=4 $0.0665, 
                  m5d.xlarge weight=4 $0.0565, r5d.xlarge weight=4 $0.072,
                  m5.xlarge weight=4 $0.048, r5.xlarge weight=4 $0.063 
AMI ID: ami-0d5d9d301c853a04a
Subnet: subnet-b3f881c9,subnet-16cecd7e,subnet-6dcc6c21
IAM fleet role: aws-ec2-spot-fleet-tagging-role
Max price: $0.083
Persistence: maintain
Key pair name: mykeyb 
IAM role: -
EBS-optimized: no
Monitoring: no
Health check: no
Tenancy: default
Interruption behavior: terminate
Classic load balancers: -
Target groups: -
Request valid from: 11/26/2019, 5:03:40 PM
Request valid until: 11/26/2020, 5:03:40 PM
Terminate instances at expiration: yes
```

Comment: If your spot instance is in an autoscaling group, you need to delete the autoscaling group, otherwise AWS will keep starting new instances to keep your autoscaling group at its target number of hosts.

Comment: Thank you.  If I right-click on the `Instance ID` then scroll to `Instance Setting` I see the option to `Attach to Auto Scaling Group`.  I cannot find an option to delete an `Auto Scaling Group`.

Comment: If I go to the web page that says `Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling helps maintain the availability of your applications` I see an option to `Create Auto Scaling group`.  I do not see any existing groups listed or an option to delete any.

Comment: Did you request a spot instance or a spot fleet (of 1)?

Comment: @jarmod  My intention was to request a spot instance.  A spot fleet might have been generated instead, but if so it was not intentional.  I have since located a "Persistence" option that is set to "maintain" and "Request type" says "fleet".

Comment: Spot fleet attempts to maintain its target capacity if your spot Instances are interrupted so will presumably launch new ones (within spot price constraints) if you terminate them.

Comment: How do I permanently terminate the instance?

Comment: Is anything listed in the **Spot Requests** page? If so, can you _Cancel spot request_?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein  Thank you.  That seems to have solved the problem.  If you post your comment as an answer I will accept it within 24 hours assuming the problem does not return.  I have never cross-posted until today.  I asked this same question a couple of minutes ago on the AWS forum.

Answer (score 3):

If instances keep "coming back to life" after termination, it is either due to:

- Auto Scaling groups
- Spot Fleets

Deleting the Auto Scaling group or Spot Request should prevent more instances being launched.